# yo generate with tabs instead of spaces

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm going to use the angular generator for this example. All files that have indentation are generated with a 2 spaces indentation by default but I want to use tabs instead.

Is there a way to let yo know that I want to use tabs *before* generating the app?

edit: it seems this is underway but not available as of now.
See https://github.com/yeoman/generator/issues/460

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 0.18, generators can use gulp plugins to process file writes. This allows generators to ask a user their preferred indentation and apply it to the output.

You can see more about this technical detail on the release announcement: http://yeoman.io/blog/release-0.18.html

It is important to note that every generator is free to implement that feature. It is not something `yo` will (or can) enforce on his own. So feel free to open tickets on the generators you'd like to see implementing that feature.